# How to place two aligned buttons below google map in Android

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, button

How do I place two buttons below google map in Android?

I use this code below it works fine but the problem
 is the map are also behind the buttons. I want to set the height of the map above the buttons. How
 will I be able to resize the map and place the bottom of the map above the two buttons equally
 distributed from the center?

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:text="Button" />

<EditText
  android:id="@+id/editText1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
  android:ems="10" >
  <requestFocus />
  </EditText>

<Button
 android:id="@+id/maptype"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hello"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view"
 android:text="First" />
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/map"
    android:layout_marginTop="346dp"
    android:text="Second" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/map"` in `@+id/hello button` try `android:layout_above="@+id/maptype"` in fragment.
Note that I have to remove the class in fragment and add the android:name for it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/maptype"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    />
    <!--class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />-->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="10" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/maptype"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view"
    android:text="First" />
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view"
    android:layout_marginTop="346dp"
    android:text="Second"
    />
    <!--android:layout_alignTop="@+id/map"-->
```

`</RelativeLayout>`

EDIT: Link for full XML:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/75c66e9b4266d45d6b62#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: I tried your code and it forces close.. I cant seem to find the problem

Comment: I have force close issue when using class: class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment", therefore, i removed it and use xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

Comment: Yes, its working perfectly just what I wanted, but can you provide a sample code with 3 buttons?

Comment: @IvanFuertes 3 buttons in a row of relativelayout will not really nice. The middle button will be smaller than other 2. Anyway, you can try with this code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6a97b93357f18ab4e38c Please mark as answered :)

Answer (score 2):

try to set the map fragment's layout_height to 0dp and layout_weight to 1.
this worked fine for me! before, everything below the map was simply invisible.
this link might be useful :
[Create buttons below google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932534/create-buttons-below-google-map)