# Create buttons below google map

Tags: android, google-maps, button

I want to add two aligned buttons below google map.I have tried adding buttons below but its not showing and whenever i try to change size of map,interface gets different for different devices. how can i do it? Please help. Here is my code given below without button code -

activity_maps.xml -

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etSearch"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="search"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:onClick="onSearch" />

</LinearLayout>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I guessed right your problem is that any Buttons below the map fragment (inside the main `LinearLayout`) are not visible. This can be solved by setting the map fragment's `layout_height` to `0dp` and giving it a `layout_weight` of `1`. The UI elements above and below the map fragment should have the `layout_height` set to `wrap_content` just like you have done.

The idea is that the other UI elements use just the amount of the screen height that they need and the map fragment will then use all the remaining space. A similar approach can commonly be used in all kinds of layouts that have some elements with fixed height/width and one element that is supposed to scale to an optimal height/width.

As XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etSearch"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="search"
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:onClick="onSearch" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <!--The Buttons below the map fragment-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by specifying `layout_weight` attribute for map fragment and linear layout that holds editText and a button.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etSearch"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="search"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:onClick="onSearch" />

</LinearLayout>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

This will split the space equally for map fragment and linear layout, but feel free to try different numbers to achieve what you want

Comment: No sir,its not working. I mean i am not getting what i want. I hope you have seen uber app home screen. It has app along with search bar and some buttons below. I want to do something like that. Can you please help me out?